# Skin to Speed Up DotNetNuke Load Times During Module Development?

Tags: themes, performance, dotnetnuke, skin, dotnetnuke-5

Are there any minimalist skins for DotNetNuke that are well suited to speeding up page load times during module development?  My page loads (especially for logging in) are quite slow on my development machine and it's a completely fresh installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Mitchel Seller's [DNN Blank Skins](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/126/dotnetnuke-blank-skins.aspx) package.

However, I don't think that changing a skin makes that much difference to load times during module development. That is, to load time after changes to /bin folder. A simple way to speed up load time is to minimize the overall size of the /bin folder. You can make a copy of the production /bin folder and delete all the dlls that are not required for current module development.

Another way to minimize loaded assemblies is to **NOT** use DNN during the first stages of development. This means not inheriting from `PortalModuleBase`, but using plain aspx pages that inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`.

Both ways add extra maintenance work and other trouble. Personally, I mostly use a full DNN environment for development these days because modern hardware, and probably IIS 7.X, has improved load times significantly.

Comment: So you just develop your ASPX pages as the module pages and then port them over to DNN as User Controls (well Modules really...they don't extend the usual class at that point)

Comment: Yes. You'll need stubs for DNN framework dependencies like PortalID, ModuleID, UserID and Settings. If you need a lot of DNN framework functionality, developing ASPX first may not be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the items mentioned above, you will want to make sure that you have the performance settings setup properly to ensure that your site is running as well as it can.